# How to build war without dupliactes .class files and excluding java file using gradle

Tags: spring, gradle

In my project we are using gradle for builld war. This project follows MVC structure we have used spring technologies , now we had a three layers Controller, Service, DAO layers 
but with the support of spring injecion we can inject DAO layer into Service Layer and Service Layer into Controller ( View Layer ) but can we restrict to inject dao layer into controller layer
and service layer into dao layer if we try to do so while building war gradle should failed to build.

To achieve this task i have done the changes in  build.gradle

```
    sourceSets {
    gen {
        java {
            srcDir 'app/GeneratedSource'
        }
    }

    dao {
        java {
            srcDir 'app/JavaSource'
            exclude 'gov/fd/vc/svc/**'
        }
        compileClasspath += gen.output
    }

    svc {
        java {
            srcDir 'app/JavaSource'
            exclude 'gov/fd/vc/dao/**'
        }
        compileClasspath += gen.output
        compileClasspath += dao.output
    }

     main {
        java {
            srcDir 'web/JavaSource'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'app/GeneratedSource'
            srcDir 'app/JavaSource'
            srcDir 'web/JavaSource'
        }
        compileClasspath += svc.output
    }
}

configurations {
    genCompile.extendsFrom compile
    daoCompile.extendsFrom compile
    svcCompile.extendsFrom compile
}
```

by doing above changes if we try to inject dao layer into controller layer  build process wil get failed .The problem is here  while building war all the .java and duplicate .class file are generated and seen in 
the targeted directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Just change main to java now there will no duplicate strategy and include of .java files in war

```
sourceSets {
        gen {
            java {
                srcDir 'app/GeneratedSource'
            }
        }

        dao {
            java {
                srcDir 'app/JavaSource'
                exclude 'gov/fd/vc/svc/**'
            }
            compileClasspath += gen.output
        }

        svc {
            java {
                srcDir 'app/JavaSource'
                exclude 'gov/fd/vc/dao/**'
            }
            compileClasspath += gen.output
            compileClasspath += dao.output
        }

         debug {
            java {
                srcDir 'web/JavaSource'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'app/GeneratedSource'
                srcDir 'app/JavaSource'
                srcDir 'web/JavaSource'
            }
            compileClasspath += svc.output
        }
    }

    configurations {
        genCompile.extendsFrom compile
        daoCompile.extendsFrom compile
        svcCompile.extendsFrom compile
    }
```